# Animated Image / Instagram Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a plugin for this type of animated Image Gallery that is used on this page?

Scroll down to the Section "SOCIAL"
https://www.coachella.com/home/

[image]

Comment: You may be able to get the results you want after some tweaking with this: https://www.juicer.io/

Comment: Hello Alex. I looking for a plugin for the Animation not for aggregation of Social Feeds. But thanks for the Link

Comment: They seem to be using this in their page: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ not sure how they achieved that effect though. Personally, I wouldn't want that effect in my web page because of how resource intensive it is.